# Why is the usage of just linear, unitary operator that isn't necessarily self-adjoint in the middle of a bra-ket a problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, linear-algebra

In the question

> Define antilinear or antiunitary operator $Θ$ acting on the ket state and on the bra state consistently?

an [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/636331/370392) mentions that the bra-ket $⟨β|A|α⟩$ in a proper way iff $A$ is linear and self-adjoint and that such usage in the absence of a self-adjoint operator is a shortcoming of the bra-ket notation. Why is it necessary that it be linear self-adjoint like an observable? Shouldn't the action on bra be meaningful as long as the operator has an adjoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the notation is *ambiguous*.  Interpreted as $\langle \beta \lvert A \rvert \alpha \rangle = \langle \beta , A \alpha \rangle$ (where on the right I have reverted to the unambiguous math notation)$-$i.e., $A$ is understood to act to the *right*, then everything is fine.  But the symmetric "look" of the notation suggests that $A$ can act to the left, but this is only true if $A$ is self-adjoint, because by definition, then, $\langle \beta , A \alpha \rangle = \langle A\beta , \alpha \rangle$, whereas interpreting
$$
\langle \beta \lvert A \rvert \alpha \rangle = 
\langle \beta \rvert \left(A \rvert \alpha \rangle \right)\,,
$$
then
$$
\langle \beta \lvert A \rvert \alpha \rangle^* = 
\left(
\langle \beta \rvert \left(A \rvert \alpha \rangle \right)
\right)^*
=
\left(A \rvert \alpha \rangle \right)^{\dagger}
\lvert \beta \rangle
=\langle \alpha \rvert A^{\dagger}\rvert \beta\rangle\,,
$$
where now we can again interpret this as matrix multiplication,  i.e., $A^{\dagger}$ acts to the right.  One can see how this makes a difference. For more details, see [this answer and the answers in the duplicate question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/744040/83835).